# Foundation tabs content transition slide

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

While using foundation's tabs what would be the best way to transition the content so it looked like it was sliding left or right? JQuery, MotionUI, or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Foundation Sites currently requires jQuery. So you can still use jQuery.
The best solution is to use MotionUI as it gives you all needed transitions and options and eases the development.

In general it is recommended to prefer CSS before JavaScript as CSS Transitions have a much better performance.